# How to debug the adding of an SSIS Custom Source Component to the SSIS Toolbox in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, bids, ssis-2012

I'm attempting to develop a custom SSIS source component.

I have used this to help me get up and running: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/developing-a-custom-ssis-source-component/

I have set up the post-build process of the project to uninstall the library from the GAC, install the new build, and copy the dll into the PipelineComponent folders, and I have managed to get the component to show up in the SSIS toolbox.

Upon adding some extra classes and rebuilding the solution the component disappears from the SSIS toolbox. Is there any way I can debug why the component does not appear? As VS automatically adds the component (or not in this case) I've no idea where to look for errors.

Any help would be much appreciated!